# Creating tabs with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in these things so this might be an easy one. I want to create tabs with the following code from w3schools. The original one is here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

I don't want images to be in the *tabcontent* section. So I made a new class named *tabimage* and added it to the javascript. Also I've added new events with the image's ids at the html. But it keeps showing other tabs when clicked. Can anyone help?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent tabimage");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += "active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Open Sans;}
.order {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
  
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabimage {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London'); openCity(event, 'London1')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris'); openCity(event, 'Paris1')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
  
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/800x600_Wallpaper_Blue_Sky.png?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" id="London1">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/Auckland_Skyline_800x600_80c6b2c0-28bc-4885-8440-a6da7de39c82.jpg?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" id="Paris1">
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName("tabcontent tabimage")` would select all elements that have the class `tabcontent` _and_ the class `tabimage`. Of which there are exactly _none_ in your given HTML.

Comment: are you sure? there are 3 tabcontent and 2 tabimage classes

Comment: I said _and_, not _or_. There are no elements that have _both_, and that is what this syntax would select, as the examples under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName#examples clearly show/explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cbroe pointed out in the comments:

If you use multiple classes with the function [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) then this function will only return elements which have all of the defined classes.

You need to switch to the function [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), with this function you are able to select multiple elements defined by multiple rules. You separate the selectors with a `comma`, e.g.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent, .tabimage");
```

Here is an example with `querySelectorAll`. Do notice I've changed the function `openCity` to show the city as the image, if there is any.

---

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent, .tabimage");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
  
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    if (document.getElementById('img'+cityName)) {
        document.getElementById('img'+cityName).style.display = "block";
    }  
    evt.currentTarget.className += "active";
}
```

```css
.order {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
  
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabimage {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
  
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/800x600_Wallpaper_Blue_Sky.png?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" id="imgLondon">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/Auckland_Skyline_800x600_80c6b2c0-28bc-4885-8440-a6da7de39c82.jpg?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" id="imgParis">
  
  
</div>
```

---

**Aternative solution**

To create tabbed content you can also work with `data-*` attributes. Using this you can easily define multiple section to show/hide, instead of relaying on (unique) id's.

It also removes the need to define the event handler for each separate element as you can you query the chosen `data-*` attribute.

In this case I'm linking the `data-origin` attribute with elements which have the `data-target` attribute

```js
var origins = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-origin]");

for (let i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
  origins[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Get all elements with data-origin defined
      var allOrigins = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-origin]");             
      for (i = 0; i < allOrigins.length; i++) {
          allOrigins[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      
      // Get all elements with data-target defined
      var allTargets = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-target]");
      for (i = 0; i < allTargets.length; i++) {
          allTargets[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      
      //Only get elements of which the data-target attribute matches the value of the data-origin of the clicked  element
      var targets = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-target='"+e.target.dataset.origin+"']");   
      for (i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
          targets[i].style.display = "block";      
      }
      
      e.target.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.order {
  display: grid;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
  
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabimage {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-origin="London">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-origin="Paris">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-origin="Tokyo">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div data-target="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

<div data-target="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div data-target="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
  
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/800x600_Wallpaper_Blue_Sky.png?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" data-target="London">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0044/8718/4457/files/Auckland_Skyline_800x600_80c6b2c0-28bc-4885-8440-a6da7de39c82.jpg?v=1646897329" class="tabimage" data-target="Paris">
  
  
</div>
```